# Замена присвоения := из Pascal на = из C++ при помощи #define

Tags: c++

Возможно ли как-нибудь заменить присвоение из Pascal на С++ при помощи #define?

```
#define :=  =
```

Comment: нет, так нельзя, после define должен быть идентификатор, а := им не является. Но Вы всегда можете написать свой препроцессор и дать его компилятору.

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать "грязый хак" -- перед запуском компилятора сделать копию исходной програмы, модифицировать ее, например, пропустив через sed, и скомпилировать. Обычно IDE позволяет прописать пре- и постпроцессоры для компилятора в настройках проекта. Если нет, то нужно написать скрипт, котороый делает это и указать IDE, что это и есть ваш компилятор.